# Covariance between lognormal and normal random variable

Tags: covariance

Good evening,

I have the following question:
Lets assume X is normally distribued and Y is log normal. Now, i want to obtain the covariance between both random variables.
I am aware that: Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)*E(Y)

While E(X) and E(Y) are easy to obtain, can somebody give me a (closed form) solution for E(XY)?

Best,
Thomas

Comment: The problem as stated is incomplete.  You need to specify a relationship between X and Y.  If they are independent E(XY)=E(X)E(Y).

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).